# JSON convert to javascript array does not work

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

With "data" being JSON, why does this script not work? I am using "$.parseJSON(data);" to convert the JSON to an array, and the last line of code is how I would typically access the resulting array.

```
{
    "refTopic": [
        {
            "REFTOPICABV": "Purpose",
            "REFTOPICVALUE": "Purpose and Need",
            "REFTOPICID": 65
        },
        {
            "REFTOPICABV": "Description",
            "REFTOPICVALUE": "Project Description",
            "REFTOPICID": 66
        }
    ]
}
```

```
if (refTopic == undefined) {
    getTopicsSelectBox(function(data) {
        console.log(typeof data);               //string
        var refTopic = $.parseJSON(data);
        console.log(typeof refTopic);           //object
        console.log(refTopic instanceof Array); //false

        console.log(refTopic[i].REFTOPICID);    //undefined
    });
}
```

Comment: Try `refTopic['refTopic'][0]['REFTOPICID']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing one level of referencing, it should be:

`refTopic.refTopic`

This is because you wrote:

`var refTopic = $.parseJSON(data);`, so the variable is the entire object, not specifically `refTopic` inside it.

I'd just write like this to be more clear:

```
var refTopicObj = $.parseJSON(data);
console.log(typeof refTopicObj);           
console.log(refTopicObj.refTopic instanceof Array);    
console.log(refTopicObj.refTopic[i].REFTOPICID);
```